# How does the increase of heat increases the speed of a particle?

Tags: thermodynamics, speed

I am fairly new to the thermodynamics topic, I have been introduced that as the temperature of a particle increases, so does the speed of the particle; it moves faster. However, I never been told how and why does the temperature increase speed.
So, in what way does the increase of temperature increase the speed?

Comment: Note that heat is NOT temperature.  Higher temperature equates to higher average kinetic energy of the particles of a substance.  "Higher heat" is an incorrect description of this fact.

Comment: No one explained why they speed up. Can you explain how the Earth can have a pressurized core that burns constantly with no oxygen? Does air get to the core? What feeds it? Eruption occurs; does that mean gases are drawn into the core as well as expelled? If you took a ball of mud and injected a molten iron core into it, then kept packing more mud around it until you can't feel the heat anymore, and then if you put that in a kiln and baked the thing to brick, shrinking it and increasing the pressure; would that core stay molten, or would it cool? [...]

Comment: continued [...] Does pressure keep the heat in or is it a gastight seal that stops heat escaping? Can you pressurize heat itself? There must be something in this science that can create a never ending source of energy. Also, why don't we feel centrifugal force from the Earth spinning; and can we not use the Earth's spin as an energy source?

Answer (score 2):

The particles in an ideal gas have a continuous distribution of speeds that depends on the temperature. The distribution is known as the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution).

The most probable speed is $\sqrt{2kT/m}$, where $k$ is Boltzmann’s constant, $T$ is the absolute temperature, and $m$ is the mass of one molecule of the gas.

As DWin explained, a higher temperature corresponds to a higher kinetic energy per molecule.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the causal arrow is in the other direction: something (moving walls of a pump, or hitting a solid with a hammer, or a flame applied to the surface of a container)  increases the average velocity of a set of particles and the result is that we measure an increase in temperature. The fundamental issue is that in thermodynamics, at least the statistical version you are discussing, the temperature is a bulk property while the underlying speeds and their averages in a population are the microscopic properties. The speeds are related to the average kinetic energies.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by David White heat is not temperature. Temperature is a measure of the average translational kinetic energy of the molecules of a substance, sometimes called the “kinetic temperature”.  Heat, on the other hand, is ***energy transfer*** from one substance to another solely due to a temperature difference between the substances. To help understand the difference between heat and temperature (and thus between heat and the speed of molecules) consider the following example (which is admittedly simplistic).

I have two blocks of the same material and the same amount of material. The average translational kinetic energy of the molecules of block A  (temperature of block A) is greater than the average translational kinetic energy of block B (temperature of block B). We place the two blocks in contact with one another.  The higher energy molecules of block A at the contact surface start colliding with the lower energy molecules of block B.

As a result of the collisions, on average the higher kinetic energy molecules of block B lose kinetic energy and the lower kinetic energy of those of block B gain kinetic energy. It is this ***transfer*** of kinetic energy from the molecules of A to B that, on a macroscopic level, that is called ***heat***. Heat is not the energy of the molecules themselves of the two blocks, but the transfer of energy from the molecules of one block to another.

As the process continues the average translational kinetic energy of the molecules of block A decreases (temperature decreases) and that of block B increases (temperature increases). After equilibrium is reached, and assuming there is no heat transfer from the two blocks to something other than the blocks themselves, the final temperature of the two blocks will be the average of the original temperatures.

Hope this helps.